# Read command interactively in a for loop

Tags: bash, command-line

I'd like to delete some mp3 files interactively as follows

```
$ for i in *.mp3; do mplayer "$i"; echo "$i"; sleep 5; interactive_code; done
```

The interactive_code should delete "$i" file when I press `rm`,
move it to `tmp` dir when I press `mv` or continue in a loop when I press space.

Comment: it might simplify things to use "continue in a loop if I press ENTER" instead of space-bar; would that be acceptable?

Comment: Why sleep 5?  Wouldn't you want to just wait for input?

Comment: Have you tried to use a menu option in bash? I believe this can solve your problem since you are required to enter some input in order to follow the original loop. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros, I recommend [*not* using tldp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59425/135943).  Instead, try the [Wooledge Bash Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29).

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, key is not important

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, I wasn't sure if there is wait function.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "continue in a loop"? Do you want to play the song indefinitely until you press `rm` or `mv`? Or neither delete nor move the file and continue the `for` loop with the next file? I made an answer assuming the second scenario.

Comment: @nxnev Yes, the second scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script should do the work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in ./*.mp3; do

  mplayer "${i}"
  printf '%s\n' "${i}"

  read -p 'What to do?: ' -r ans

  if [[ "${ans}" == 'rm' ]]; then
    rm "${i}"
  elif [[ "${ans}" == 'mv' ]]; then
    mv "${i}" 'tmp'
  fi

done
```

PS: It assumes that the `tmp` directory already exists and is in your current working directory. If it is in another location or you were refering to the `/tmp` directory, just change that part of the code.

Comment: Read comments; given the `read` command, no need for `sleep`.

Comment: btw. When I type `$ man read` it will display man page for read(2) not [this](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html). Can I see it from the command line as well?

Comment: @xralf `read` is a shell builtin, so you should type `$ help read` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Untested.  This isn't quite what you asked for as it gives two prompts.  Type 'y' and press enter on the *first* prompt to move the file to `/tmp` (in which case second prompt is skipped), or pass 'y' to the *second* prompt to remove the file.  Ignore both prompts (press enter) to continue with no action.

```
find *.mp3 -type f -exec mplayer {} \; \( \
  -ok mv -i {} /tmp \; -o \
  -ok rm {} \; \)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the user a menu after playing a file:

```
TMPDIR=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}

for name in ./*.mp3; do
    test -f "$name" || continue

    printf 'Playing "%s"...\n' "$name"
    mplayer "$name"

    select ch in "Move $name to $TMPDIR" "Remove $name"; do
        case "$REPLY" in
            1)  mv "$name" "$TMPDIR" ;;
            2)  rm "$name" ;;
            *)  echo 'Invalid choice' >&2
                continue ;;
        esac
        break
    done
done
```

This script does not require `bash`, any `sh` shell should do.